# Append Error Text to Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, text, append

I have a SQL update command that runs upon a button click.  I would like to do a try/catch function and use the catch function to append any errors that may get thrown to a textbox.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: The both below answers are good solutions. try that !!!

Answer (score 3):

```
catch (Exception ex) 
{
   tb.Text += ex.Message;
}
```

For read only feedback I typically use TextBlock

And if you want only SQL exceptions

```
catch (SqlException ex)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should note that i have handled a generic exception here, just to give you an idea. You should handle the more [specific exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your code though.

you can do this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
     //do your database work here
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ex.ToString();
   }
}
```